# Additional maven source folders such as src/main/javascript or src/main/css?

Tags: java, maven, directory

I've been developing a standard web app and its really annoying to have Eclipse show src/main/resources and src/main/java in such a convenient flat-package way, yet I have to frequently drill down into src/main/webapp and all its subdirectories to modify my css, js, and html files.

I've never seen a project use additional source folders for resources like those, but is it out of the question to try? Ideally I'd love to have a directory structure like

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/main/jsp
src/main/javascript
src/main/css
```

Has anyone setup a project like this? Does it become more of a hassle to even try, breaking existing plugins and whatnot?

Comment: The above sounds like a webapp and therefor put the things like jsp, javascript and css into `src/main/webapp/` folder ... so no need for supplemental resources configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add resource folders this way.

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>resource1</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>resource2</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>resource3</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

[More information](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

However, if you want multiple web resources (`WEB-INF` directory in WAR file) than you need to configure [Maven War plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/jsp</directory>
          </resource>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
          </resource>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/css</directory>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: That looks right to me.  Whether IntelliJ and Eclipse deal with that properly is another story...they should though.  The IDEs start to show their limitations when you use something like Build Helper Maven Plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to add source directories.  Cheers.

Comment: Isn't this just going to put all the resources on the classpath instead of in the WEB-INF folder where html resources need to go?

Comment: Yes it will, but this how I understood your question. You probably wanted to have multiple `webapp` directories merged into one?

Comment: Thats correct, I was looking for a way to separate my webapp resources and have them all merge into webapp at the end- thank you!